# D3 tooltip with dotted x/y axis lines, can't create multiple tooltips

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a tooltip for my line chart that sends out dotted lines to the x and y axis (identical to this d3 n00b example, but my chart has multiple lines) http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html

I have tried setting up two focus groups, tried adding the extra line info into the existing group, but all I can get is the date running on both lines but the dotted lines and data info only work on one.

Any help would be gratefully accepted.

Here is the chart with code underneath:
http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d1dbc221f95f6308b351

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable for the two *focus groups*:

```
var focus = svg.append("g")                                // tooltip
    .style("display", "none");    

var focus = svg.append("g")                                // tooltip
    .style("display", "none");
```

Name one variable `focus1` and the other `focus2` to make sure that they remain separate.

I would also recommend refactoring the code such that you don't have to call the exact same functions on both of these, once for the `CPI` line and once for `RPIJ` line. Instead, you should create a function which calls the required functions on a `focus`. You should pass the function which *line* to attach to and the correct `focus group`, i.e. `focus1` and `focus2`.

---

**Update for the edit:**

As I understand it, you have now added `text.y1`, `text.y2`, `text.y3` and `text.y4` to both the focus groups and are effectively *hiding* the unnecessary information by setting the correct `strokes` to `#fff` here:

```
// place the value at the intersection RPIJ
focus2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y1")
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", "3.5px")
    .style("opacity", 0.8)
    .attr("dx", 8)
    .attr("dy", "-.3em");
focus2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y2")
    .attr("dx", 8)
    .attr("dy", "-.3em");

// place the date at the intersection RPIJ
focus2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y3")
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", "3.5px")
    .style("opacity", 0.8)
    .attr("dx", 8)
    .attr("dy", "1em");
focus2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y4")
    .attr("dx", 8)
    .attr("dy", "1em");
```

However, while doing it you have committed a couple of unique mistakes in each case.

For `focus1`, you do not create a `text.y4` at all while for `focus2`, you update `text.RPIJ` instead of `text.y3`:

```
focus2.select("text.RPIJ")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                           y(d.RPIJ) + ")")
      .text("£" + d.RPIJ);
```

Comment: @NatalieCox Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed, renaming the two focus groups worked

Correct code:http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/b77e904f34aa2162e1df